# Approximate a distribution as mixture of $K$ other (known, fixed) distributions

Tags: optimization, mixture-distribution, approximation, finite-mixture-model

I'd like to draw samples from some "target" probability density function $f(x)$. However, I don't have a way to do that -- instead I just have access to $N$ samples, each drawn from one of $K$ "sampling" distributions $g_k(x)$ (I know which draw corresponds to which distribution).

One solution is to keep all the samples, but to weight them all. This leads to the question: how to weight the samples in order to approximate my target distribution? I'd like to preserve that all samples from each sampling distribution have the same weight. **That means that I am effectively approximating my target distribution as the mixture of the $K$ sampling distributions:**

$$f(x) \approx \hat{f}(x) = \sum_{i=k}^K w_k g_k(x)$$

My question is, how can I compute the mixture weights $w_k$ corresponding to each of the sampling distributions? I'd like to avoid making distributional (e.g., Gaussian) assumptions if possible.

Comment: 0. Welcome to CV.SE. 1. Is there a reason why couldn't we use the KDE of all samples together to sample from? Given we use a Gaussian *kernel* to construct the KDE, then the bandwidth use can be used as the standard deviation of the Gaussian distribution around any given point $x_i$.

Comment: The question as asked is unclear: what is the connection between the $N$ samples drawn amongst the $K$ distributions $g_k$ and the distribution $f$? Without further details, it does not seem possible to validate these weights.

Comment: Happy to clarify. Using a KDE to construct the $g_k(x)$ is totally appropriate. My goal is to find the mixture weights $w_k$ so that the resulting mixture $\sum_k w_k g(x)$ approximates the target distribution $f$ as closely as possible. If there is a special case in which it's easy using a Gaussian kernel, that would work for my application.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I think we can further simplify our task by working with the observed "target" probability density function $f(x)$ directly. Please see my answer below for more details and a worked example.